# Is my fingering correct for F major to G major chord change?

Tags: keyboard, fingering

I just started taking keyboard lessons. I have a song which has F major to G major chord change.

- F = C F A [Finger 5 2 1]
- G = B D G [Finger 5 3 1]

I placed my fingers on `C F A [5 2 1]` but now while moving to `B D G [Finger 5 3 1]` is not so easy. Is this is because of wrong chord in the song? Why is this transition not flexible and easy like C major to G major? C major to G major is flexible but why F to G is not easy?

Could someone please if I am doing wrong?

Comment: Really, the very best person to ask will be your teacher, who can explain while you're both at the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These fingerings look correct to me!

As for why it's not as easy as C to G, it depends on how you're voicing those two chords (we call these voicings "inversions"). But it's possible that, between C and G, you:

- Use the exact same three fingers both times.
- Only move a finger by, at most, one step.
- Have a pitch in common between the two chords (i.e., one finger stays where it is).

Whereas F moving to G has:

- One voice moving by a third.
- A switch between the second and third finger.
- No common tones between the two chords (i.e., all fingers move).

F moving to G is, quite simply, a harder progression than C moving to G. What you're doing is correct, just keep at it!

Comment: Do you teach music? I know it's off topic discussion. Just curious to know. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @codetoshare Yep, at the university level. Glad to help!

Comment: Wouldn't 421 531 be as good or even better?

Comment: @coconochao That could also work, and in some cases I could see where it would be preferable. But early on I would recommend what OP listed.

Comment: We shall have some video clips which shows finger movements. please share if it's available.